# Access container / DI in Program.cs Azure Service Fabric

Tags: .net-core, azure-service-fabric

Using the default, .Net Core DI container, is it possible to inject dependencies into a stateless SF service construction in the Program.cs Main()?

ie:

```
private static void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            ServiceRuntime.RegisterServiceAsync("Acme.Notification.ServiceType",
                context => new NotificationService(context, new DispatchConfig())).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceTypeRegistered(Process.GetCurrentProcess().Id, typeof(NotificationService).Name);

            Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            ServiceEventSource.Current.ServiceHostInitializationFailed(e.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
```

Service class - constructor only

```
     public sealed class NotificationService : StatelessService
    {
        public NotificationService(StatelessServiceContext context,
            DispatchConfig config)
        : this(context)
        {
            _config = config;            
        }
    }
```

Replace the command `new DispatchConfig()` with a container resolution - this class is hydrated from `appsettings.json` so is required to read dynamic config values.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you see this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565765/where-to-put-my-ioc-container-configuration-in-service-fabric-service

Comment: Thanks, but it uses Ninject. I'd like to avoid using a 3rd party IOC if that's at all possible. Cheers